# django's commit_on_success has no effect on number of sql queries

Tags: django

I'm trying an experiment with bulk saving objects. Using Django Debug Toolbar, I can see how many sql queries are run.  However, it seems that the decorator has no affect on the number of SQL queries - it stays the same number with or without the decorator.  Should it be decreasing?

```
@transaction.commit_on_success()
def fastsave(queryset):
    for t in queryset:
        t.save()

def test(request):
    fastsave(TimeEvent.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('test.html', {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `update` vs `save`. See docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Answer (score 3):

No. The `transaction` decorators only affect *when* the queries are finalized, not *how many* are run.

Comment: Is there any way to optimize this? I have a large queryset where I'll be updating every object, but currently this hits the database for every object and bogs things down.

Comment: If you update every object then it will hit every object. Do bulk updates via the query set when possible.